# Add attribute to specific elements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I wish to add a new attribute to all of my elements that their `type` is `text`

Can you please let me know where I'm wrong?

Firstly, I identify all my elements that their type is text as follows (input tag name  is the tag name that contains text types)

```
 var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
```

Secondly, I add my attribute to those with text type

```
if (inputs.type =='text') {var att = document.createAttribute("class")}
```

Then when I want to check if the new attribute is added or not

```
inputs.hasAttribute("class");
```

I got this error

> Uncaught TypeError: inputs.hasAttribute is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.getElementsByTagName('input');
```

returns an array like list instead of just one element. Therefore, this is what you should do:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
    if(inputs[i].type == 'text'){
        inputs[i].classList.add("some", "class");
    }
}
```

An even better way would be this:

```
// Only works in recent browsers
document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]").forEach(function(ele){
    ele.classList.add("some", "class");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  what is `some` ? in your code. and how can I test if it works? because I tried your code and I got the same error.

Comment: `inputs[i].classList.add("some", "class")` means it's adding the class names `some` and `class` to the class list. `inputs.hasAttribute("class")` will give you an error because `inputs` as I said is a list, not an element.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
    if(inputs[i].type == 'text'){
        var att = document.createAttribute("class");  
        att.value = "testClass";
        inputs[i].setAttributeNode(att);
        console.log(inputs[i].hasAttribute("class"));
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text"/>
<input type="text"/>
```